# Running two fcm android apps on the same device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I have two applications that use fcm. Thoses applications are complementary. 
They are on a separate project on Firebase console.

When they are both installed on the same device (especially on Android 7 or later). Some push notifications are not delivered.

Anyone have a clue?

I have the manifests:

I use 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2' for Firebase version

Comment: I can't see any clue. Please provide some more information.. I mean some of your approaches.

Comment: If only 1 app is installed, are notifications delivered?

Comment: yes, with one app, it works fine

Comment: Do they use same key?

Comment: they have different keys

Comment: @maheryhaja i think you need to update to the latest version, please check my answer below and tell me if it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the latest version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

And also use latest version, based on [this url](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

And if you use other libraries check below:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```

Comment: I will give a try

Comment: @maheryhaja is this fix your problem?